# Capture scientific notation and covert to string

Tags: python, regex

I need to capture occurrences of scientific notation in a string and convert the notation in string format using python.

e.g E-100 and/or e-100 should be represented as 1E-100 in string format.

So far I have following code

```
>>> import re
>>> num = "My numbers are E-100 and e-100"
>>> print(num)
```

My numbers are E-100 and e-100

```
>>> re.findall('[eE]?[+-]?\d+(?:\.\d+)?(?:[eE][+-]?\d+)?', num)
```

['E-100', 'e-100']

This prints numbers as a list.

How can I convert each of this number to 1E-100 and print in string format.

Update: This should work with all numbers e.g 2e-123 should be represented in string format as 2E-123

Thanks in advance !!

Comment: What is wrong with `f"1{string.upper()}"`?

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: my expected output is 1E-100. This should be applicable to all numbers. Example e+07 or E-234 or 2e-09 should be represented as 1E+07, 1E-234, 2E-09 respectively.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use replace operation.

Code:

```
import re
num = "My numbers are E-100, e-100, e+07, E-234, 2e-09 "
arr = re.findall('[eE]?[+-]?\d+(?:\.\d+)?(?:[eE][+-]?\d+)?', num)

for i in range(len(arr)):
    arr[i] = arr[i].replace('e', 'E')
    if arr[i][0] == 'E':
        arr[i] = arr[i].replace('E', '1E')

print(arr)
```

Output:

```
['1E-100', '1E-100', '1E+07', '1E-234', '2E-09']
```

Comment: Thanks this works, can you please explain what this syntax does arr[i] = arr[i].replace('e', 'E')
    if arr[i][0] == 'E':
        arr[i] = arr[i].replace('E', '1E')

Comment: replace(old, new) # replace old with new #
replace 'e' with 'E', now if 1st char is not a number replace 'E' with '1E'